# Status of a threads vs. status of a process

Tags: process, thread

Do all threads of a specific process share the same status (D, R, S, ...) or may there be differences among these threads?

If so, where in `/proc` do I find information about the status of a certain thread? I am reading the process status from the `/proc/<PID>/status` files at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different threads can certainly be in a different scheduler state at the same time. In fact, if they're all in the same state, that's a coincidence (except for stopped (Z), because that affects the whole process).

The subdirectory `/proc/PID/task` contains a subdirectory per thread of the process. The files in this directory are mostly the same as in the per-process directory. Some of the information is just duplicated (e.g. memory-related information, environment, privileges, etc.). Information that's specific to a thread, such as the scheduler state (running/sleeping/IO/…), can differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ps` command to find out about the status of all the threads of a process:

```
ps H -p 27901
```

This will show all the threads related to process 27901 and their status.

Comment: Thank you! I would rather prefer to not use an external program but to rather read these information from `\proc` directly

Comment: OK. By the way `ps` gets its information from proc file system. This could be useful http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html